# How to realloc 2d struct pointer with different size

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct, malloc, realloc

I want to realloc 2d pointer array. It must be dynamic as follows ascii

```
+=====+==============+==============+==============+==============+======+
|     | [0]          | [1]          | [2]          | [3]          | [..] |
+=====+==============+==============+==============+==============+======+
| [0] | 'a'          | 'b'          | 'c'          | 'd'          |      |
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| [1] | object[0][0] | object[1][0] | object[2][0] | object[3][0] |      |
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| [2] | object[0][1] | object[1][1] | object[2][1] | object[3][1] |      |
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| [3] | object[0][2] | object[1][2] | object[2][2] |              |      |
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| [4] | object[0][3] |              | object[2][3] |              |      |
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| [5] | object[0][4] |              |              |              |      |
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| [6] | object[0][5] |              |              |              |      |
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+
```

In this table every cols size is different. How can i do this with 2d struct. I allocated matrix with malloc. But i want to realloc second index. Like this matrix[25][n]. N must be realloc for every column with different size. But it must be on runtime

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    char word[20];
}Dictionary;

Dictionary **object;
void initializeDictionary()
{
     // Create matrix [29][1]
     object=(Dictionary**)malloc(29 * sizeof(Dictionary*));
     object[0]=(Dictionary*)malloc(1*sizeof(Dictionary));
}
```

Comment: Why does the row index 4 have a gap in column index 1?  Does that mean that the pointer there is null?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: OP is considering data on a per column basis so that first index is selecting a column.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, I've just realized that the OP is not using the normal `array[row][col]` notation but is using `array[col][row]`, which is guaranteed to confuse — me, at least, and quite possibly them, and maybe other semi-attentive readers on SO.

Comment: yes the same as you said @JonathanLeffler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pointers this comes naturally. In your code you have a `Dictionary**` which indeed is a pointer to pointer to Dictionary. But you can see it an array of `Dictionary*` in which each pointer points to a different sized array of `Dictionary` objects.

```
Dictionary** objects;
const int COLUMNS = 29;

objects = malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(Dictionary*));

objects[0] = malloc(2 * sizeof(Dictionary)); // first column 2 elements
objects[1] = malloc(3 * sizeof(Dictionary)); // second column 3 elements

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS; ++i)
  free(objects[i]);

free(objects);
```

Comment: I compiled your code. When i trying this code:
objects[0] = malloc(2 * sizeof(Dictionary)); ..//
I can access and assign *(objects[0][100]).word .
should not have to be a maximum of 2? why i can access 100?

Comment: Because it's your duty to avoid undefined behavior, the language itself doesn't prevent you from doing wrong things. You are not accessing valid memory.

Comment: I need to increase the size without deleting data at runtime

Comment: then either you `malloc` another array, `memcpy` the elements and replace the pointer or you use `realloc` which already does it for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. How to use realloc for m index for example [k] [m]

Comment: Documentation exists for your personal fruition: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc